# Letting users drop the file(s) to what location they want from the listview on Qt

Tags: linux, qt, drag-and-drop

I want to make a function to let users drag and drop the file(s) between the location they want and the listview current location on Qt.

[image]

How to implement this function?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to google? If you are, you'll find this result:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html

For your code, this could be something like this:

```
void YourWidget::dragObject (const QString& text)
{
    QDrag * drag = new QDrag(this); // note that this must be an instance of QWidget

    QMimeData * mime = new QMimeData();
    mime->setText(text);

    drag->setMimeData(mime);
    // ...

    Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec();
}
```